# Was Boomhauer really a Texas Ranger?

Tags: character, king-of-the-hill

On one of the final episodes of *King of the Hill*, Boomerhaur's occupation, which was never previously discussed (other than being a ladies' man who sometimes had benefactors) was possibly revealed as being a Texas Ranger.

Specifically, it showed his wallet, with a Texas Ranger badge.

[image: Jeff Boomhauer]

Was he really a Texas Ranger though, or was this just something he used to get ladies?

It seemed to me like he couldn't be a Texas Ranger for several reasons:

- His trademark near-incomprehensible way of speaking would make it difficult or impossible for him to deal with either citizens or suspects profesionally
- He did a number of illegal things with Hank, Dale, and Bill (though admittedly law enforcement employees break the law all the time, so this is a weak point)
- There were a number of times when he and the guys needed law enforcement, like when they were being terrorized by a former NFL player who the cops wouldn't arrest due to his star power, but he never showed his badge or said he was a Ranger
- He was involuntarily committed to an insane asylum for wandering the street in his underwear and seeming to have threatened a cop

Comment: I thought this was one of the best reveals of the series. I choose to believe he is a Ranger.

Comment: @Dpeif Yea, I tell you what, I thought it would've been great it they did it a little earlier and made at least 1 episode on it to answer some dang ole questions and clear it up man, if he's a Ranger or if it's one of his lady-killing tricks. He is my favorite character. I'm just not even sure which was their intent. I guess he's really supposed to be a Ranger.

Comment: "His trademark near-incomprehensible way of speaking would make it difficult or impossible for him to deal with either citizens or suspects profesionally" What are you talking about? Are you not able to understand his speech? Maybe you have a hearing problem. I don't think anyone else has a problem understanding him.